# Link containing floated content has no height

Tags: css, css-float

I have a list of links. Inside the links is an img floated left and a div floated right. Because of the floats the link collapses to no height. I have applied overflow:auto to the links, but this doesn't make any difference, nor does display:block. Thank you for your help.

```
a {
  overflow: auto;
  display: block;
  background-color:yellow;
}
li img {
  width: calc(50% - 1.8rem);
  float: left;
}
.text {
  width: calc(50% - 1.8rem);
  float: right;
}


<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="aaa.html">
      <img src="aaa.png">
      <div class="text">Lots of lovely text</div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="bbb.html">
      <img src="bbb.jpg">
      <div class="text">More nice words</div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: your div in HTML has `test` class, no `list_test` like in CSS. Apart from that it works as expected

Comment: Thank you, I've relooked at it and you're right. My silly mistake

Answer (score 0):

If you apply a clearfix to the anchor tag:

```
a:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

You force the anchor tags to self-clear its children.